# Какой командой уменьшить иконки на рабочем столе?

Tags: cmd, bat, icon, desktop

Подскажите пожалуйста какой командой можно уменьшить иконки на рабочем столе?
В итоге хочу получить исполняемый `cmd` файл

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону редактирования файла desktop.ini с помощью cmd. В нём содержится конфигурация всего рабочего стола пользователя.

[Документация](https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/desktopini.html)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение на свой вопрос.

1. Создаем файл к примеру `power.bat` и добавляем его в автозагрузку.
2. Открываем его в обычном текстовом редакторе.
3. Прописываем туда:

`@echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop" /v "IconSize" /t REG_DWORD /d 24 /f
explorer.exe
exit`

Цифра `24` это и есть размер иконок.

`24 - small icons
 48 - medium icons (по умолчанию по всех windows)
 72 - large icons`

Как я понял чтобы изменения вступили в силу нужно убить процесс `explorer.exe`, а затем заново его запустить.

Данное решение я использую для загрузочного `WinPE 10 (x64)`

Пока не придумал как напрямую реестр изменить в архиве `wim`

Comment: С помощью фирменной утилиты imagex от Microsoft монтируйте и перепаковывайте файлы WIM. Файлы реестра для редактирования напрямую подключаются с помощью утилиты regedit.